# How to create a costum template structure like for pages and post but for different entities like hotels, products etc 

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi everyone I am creating a wordpress theme and a custom plug-in which is related to hotel booking and display the information on the front end entered in the back end in admin panel of wordpress .
so friends whenever a post is displayed the url is like `http://localhost/wordpress/uncategorized/post10/` and the name of the post or id of the post changes in a url but at the back end only single.php template get used by wordpress again and again so my question is can wee create something like that for different things for example in my case to display hotel only hotel.php file get used again and again and in url only the id of the hotel changes .

I didn't searched much about this on internet but I have seen something like that in wp-e-commerce plugin in which there is a separate template files to display the categories of products and also for products and those files are in the plugin directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create custom post type (you will find plugins for that), for example a `hotel` post type.

Then you can easily create specific template for this post type, for example `single-hotel.php`.

More on codex :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files

Comment: Thanks soju for your help I think this is the solution I have bean looking for.